# Remove GtkButton's image padding (inner-border)?

Tags: c, gtk

In C/GTK, is there a way to remove the inner-border for a GtkButton that has an image using gtk_button_set_image?

`gtk_button_set_relief (GTK_BUTTON (button), GTK_RELIEF_NONE);` sort of did the job but a mouseover showed that it merely hides it.

I would prefer to do this without using an RC style, but if there's no other way, an example on how to use the RC styles would be appreciated.

Basically, I need a way of not having the "glow" effect when the mouse hovers a GtkButton.

---

*Note: Also, this is the latest stable version of gtk+ 2.0*

Answer (score 0):

You can use GtkStyle to disable the "glow" button.

Example :

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void destroy (GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data){
    gtk_main_quit();
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[]){

    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *button;
    GtkStyle *style;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    /* window */
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL); 
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW (window), "my Program");
    gtk_widget_set_usize(window,200,150);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW (window),GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    gtk_signal_connect (GTK_OBJECT (window), "destroy", GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC(destroy),NULL);

    /* Create a new button (NO GLOW) */
    button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Exit");
    /*-------------------------------------------------------------*/
    style = gtk_widget_get_style(button);
    style->bg[GTK_STATE_PRELIGHT] = style->bg[GTK_STATE_NORMAL];
    gtk_widget_set_style(button, style);
    /*-------------------------------------------------------------*/
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), button);
    gtk_signal_connect (GTK_OBJECT (button), "clicked", GTK_SIGNAL_FUNC (destroy), NULL);


    gtk_widget_show(button);
    gtk_widget_show(window);
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```